# How can I insert an ajax multiple file loader into django admin form?

Tags: python, ajax, django, forms, django-admin

In my django project I'm having a model containing (above all) multiple audio files with their descriptors. Descriptor is an info, that can be obtained from the audio file itself with some preprocessing.

So I wanted to have an ajax form inside of my django admin model form, which could load multiple files, process them and display the resulted descriptors for each file uploaded (without saving the whole model form).

What is important, that files has to be loaded automatically, because there can be a lot of audios attached to each model entity.
I made a fake field in admin model and wrote a custom widget for it, like this:

```
<form action="process_and_load_samples/" method="POST" id="samples_form">
    <input name="samples" id="id_samples" type="file" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="load samples" form="samples_form">
</form>
```

But when I load the admin page, I see that django somehow stripped off my form tags and included my custom inputs inside the model form.

1. How can implement such loader?
2. Why and how does django stripes off form tags?